# Websocket wss connection does not work in Firefox 89 on localhost

Tags: angular, typescript, firefox, websocket

Websocket wss connection does not work in Firefox 89 on localhost.

When I use my https://client.com and I try to connect to https://server.com websocket connection from the production server, it works.

When I try to start the connection from localhost:4200(client) to localhost:5001(server), it does not work.

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://localhost:5001/hub
Error: Failed to start the connection: null

I allowed the connection in firefox config, but it did not fix the issue.

[Firefox Config for websockets image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNZBS.png)

Comment: Try via 127.0.0.1 and with your system IP - with ports instead of localhost url

Answer (score 2):

The fix was that the I had to reach the https://localhost:5001/hub from the browser window and accept the certificate. After that when it tried to establish WS connection it worked.